# In Flutter Web, after deploying the web app the dropdown widget is not showing but in the local build it is working properly

Tags: flutter

In Flutter Web, after deploying the web app the dropdown widget is not showing but in the local build it is working properly.

dropdown is completely an empty box. expanded to a particular extend then below it other widgets are coming.

in local build

[image]

in hosted web app

[image]

dropdown widget code

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Expanded not a direct child to the column or row. It can cause the issue you described. Try to remove Expanded and look at the release mode.